# Is it possible to insert into a file without copying the end of the file

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to insert into a large file, but I do not want to copy the part that is behind the insertion point. Is there a way to do this (of course with restrictions from the file system)? I'm thinking along the lines that the file system is normally organized in blocks & inserting a full block between 2 blocks should be cheap. Does anyone know if and how this could be done on win32 systems?

Comment: yes, it's a duplicate. Thank you - I did not find it.

Comment: It was presented to you as part of a long list of possible duplicates as you wrote your question. Please take more care in the future.

Comment: yes, but it's title misses the important part - without copying. It's title also does not mention that the file is large. And in general, I know how it is possible to insert into a file using win32 api

Comment: It is possible to click on the title and read the actual question. It only takes a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no.  The OS doesn't support this, and for
file systems like those used by Windows or Unix, it's difficult
to see how they could.  It's true that physically, the file
itself is split into allocation blocks, but the size of these
blocks varies from drive to drive, not to mention from file
system to file system (and you'll often have several different
file systems mounted), and the utility of a function which
allows you to insert, but only multiples of *n* bytes, at
a position which is itself a multple of *n* bytes, probably
seems of too limited utility to be worthwhile.  And supporting
it would still entail copying, since the blocks containing the
pointers to these blocks would have to be copied.

Answer (score -1):

You can truncate, append new data, append remaining old data.

Comment: You'd still have to read the old data at the end first.  And the results wouldn't be pleasant if your program was terminated right after the truncation.

Comment: @JamesKanze: No matter what you do, you can break it. Pull the power while the hard disk cache is being emptied and let me know what happens

Comment: The usual techniques always leave a consistent state somewhere.  You don't remove or modify the source until the destination has been successfully written.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It depends what you're doing. If you're manipulating a 500GB file then, no, you probably don't leave a consistent state somewhere unless you count your daily backups _[disclaimer: I entirely jest]_